# What does it mean creating an instance variable outside a class and inside a method?

Tags: ruby

What does it mean in the ruby language to create an instance variable outside of a class?

e.g:

```
def my_method:
  @animal = "cat"
end
```

I've also seen it written outside of a method, like this:

```rb
@foo = "bar"
```

Is this just sugar syntax?

thanks!

Comment: If you write a method without any class, then that method will be wrapped inside the object class. So those are the instance variable inside Object class.

Answer (score 2):

> what it means to create instance of variable outside class in ruby?

Instance variables have nothing to do with classes. They belong to *objects*, i.e. *instances*, that's why they are *called* "instance" variables.

> ```ruby
> def my_method
>   @animal = "cat"
> end
> ```

This does not create an instance variable. It creates a *method* named `my_method`, which *when you call it* assigns to the instance variable named `@animal`.

There is nothing special about this. When you call this method, it will assign to the `@animal` instance variable of whatever object you call this method on, just like any other method that assigns an instance variable.

For example here:

```ruby
class Foo
  def my_method
    @animal = 'cat'
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Foo.new
```

If you call `foo.my_method`, it will assign to the instance variable `@animal` of `foo`, if you call `bar.my_method`, it will assign to the instance variable `@animal` of `bar`.

There is actually nothing different between those two examples as far as the instance variable is concerned.

The only interesting question is "Which class is the method defined in?" But that has nothing to do with instance variables.

Methods defined on the top-level become *private* instance methods of `Object`.

> ```ruby
> @foo = "bar"
> ```

Again, this is no different than any other assignment to an instance variable. This assigns to the instance variable named `@foo` of whatever object `self` is at the moment.

From an instance variable standpoint, there is absolutely nothing special about this. `@foo = 'bar'` *always* means "assign to the instance variable named `@foo` of whatever object `self` is at the moment". There is nothing else it *can* mean.

The only interesting question is: "What *is* `self` at this point?" But that has nothing to do with instance variables.

At the top-level, `self` is always the anonymous object commonly called `main` in the Ruby community.

> is just sugar sintaxe?

No, this is not syntactic sugar for anything. It's just an assignment like any other assignment. There is absolutely nothing special about it.

Comment: What I find wierd about this is that regular methods at the toplevel (e.g. `def foo; end`) get added as instance methods of Object, but instance variables only seem to get applied to `main` (the instance of Object) so they're not passed around to  other classes (which inherit from Object).

Comment: There's nothing special about that, though. Instance variables *always* end up on `self`, methods *always* end up on the *default definee*. *Generally*, the default defined is the closest lexically enclosing module definition, but at the top-level *there is no* lexically enclosing context, so there's two choices: disallow method definitions because there is no default definee or find a suitable default definee, and I think making them `private` methods of `Object` is a good choice.

Comment: Ok cool, so it sounds like there _is_ some special casing of methods on the top level, to determine the "default definee". Because it is not `self` here, as you say, it is actually Object

Comment: No, there is no special casing for methods. Methods are *always* defined on the *default definee*. The default definee, *in general* is the closest lexically enclosing module definition body … except when it isn't. The two main exceptions are reflective methods like `Module#class_eval`, `Module::new` and `Class::new`, and the top-level. It is important to keep special casing out of methods, for performance reasons. Methods should be as straight-forward as possible. `self` and the default definee are two separate concepts and contexts, really, the only place where they happen to be the same …

Comment: … object is inside a module definition body.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this on the command line:

```rb
% ruby -e "puts self; puts self.class"
main
Object
```

You'll see at the top-level scope (not inside a `class` or `module`), you'll be in the scope of an instance of `Object` called `main`.

What you already know about using instance variables and defining methods etc are the same for `main` as it is for `class` and `module`.

```rb
class Foo
end

foo_main = Foo.new    # create instance of `Foo`

class Foo
  self                # then, inside scope of class `Foo`
  # => Foo

  def foo             # define instance method for class `Foo`
    puts "foo"
  end
end

foo_main.foo          # calls method on an instance of `Foo`
# => foo

# at the top level, it's as if the Ruby runtime has already done something
# like "Object.new" and then put you "inside" the created instance

my_main = self        # inside scope of `main` already
# => main

def bar               # define instance method for class `Object`
  puts "bar"
end

# below are all equivalent
my_main.bar
self.bar
bar                   # implied `self` is main, an instance of `Object`
```

You may have noticed:

- inside `Foo`, `self` returns `Foo`, a class
- at top-level, `self` returns `main`, an instance of class `Object`

Although it seems like they're two different things, what makes Ruby work the way it does is they're actually the same! More *specifically*, it's:

- inside `Foo`, `self` returns `Foo`, an instance of class `Class`
- at top-level, `self` returns `main`, an instance of class `Object`